# AppCode workspaces and TFS command-line client tool

Tags: appcode, team-explorer-everywhere

I can create a workspace with AppCode and successfully can check in and out of TFS. This is all good.But when i use the [Cross-platform Command-Line Client for TFS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg413282%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and try to see these workspaces i created with AppCode, i am getting back "No local workspaces found". AppCode does not really create a workspace then because according to msdn the name of the workspace owner and the name of the computer on which the workspace is used are stored in Team Foundation Server.

I have other applications that needs access to this workspace created by AppCode. They can use the TFS command line client tool to run TFS commands but because of the reason i mentioned above, they see no workspace.

Any suggestions to sync AppCode created workspaces and TFS client workspaces so i can have  all my apps be aware of the same workspace? or any other suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with AppCode, but if it's anything like IntelliJ (their Java IDE) then they've written their own TFS integration.  If that's the case, then they likely have not updated the cache files that are necessary for `tf` to find its workspaces.

If that is the case, then you should simply need to run a command that will cause `tf` to connect to your server - at which point it will populate the necessary cache files.  For example, if you pass the `-collection` flag to `tf workspaces`, then it will actually query the server for the list of workspaces (and rebuild necessary cache files in the process.)

That is to say:

```
tf workspaces
```

Only works on the local workspace cache, while:

```
tf workspaces -collection:http://tfs.contoso.com:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection
```

Will connect to the server.