# Intellij TFS plugin and TEE using different workspaces

Tags: tfs, intellij-idea, osx-mountain-lion, team-explorer-everywhere

I'm attempting to sync Intellij's built in TFS plugin workspace with the one used by [TEE's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg413282%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) command line 'tf' command on OSX Mountain Lion and failing miserably.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589869/appcode-workspaces-and-tfs-command-line-client-tool) appears to be very similar to mine, however it has no reference to what one should do when the computer name reported by each tool is different.

Intellij says my computer name is the fully qualified domain name (ex: hostname.domain.com) whereas the 'tf workspaces' command reports the computer name to be just the the hostname (ex: hostname).  Consequently, they are unable to use the same workspace.  I do know that you can change the computer name of a workspace, but I'd like to use both at the same time as we have some ant tasks using the 'tf' command locally.  Our Windows users in the group are able to do this just fine.

Is there any way to make these tools report the same thing for the computer name? I believe I could then use the 'tf workspaces' command and enable me to use both at the same time in the same workspace. Much obliged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not supported (according to the responsible developer). Please [submit a request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA) and we'll see what can be done to make it work.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response :) Added a request for this feature - http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-93304

Comment: I just upgraded to Intellij 12 and this is now working fine thanks to the improvements made in response to this issue.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Team Explorer Everywhere allows you to override your local hostname with the `computerName` system property.  You can edit your `tf` launcher script to match what IntelliJ is using.  You can change the last few lines of the file to be:

```
exec java -Xmx512M -classpath "$CLC_CLASSPATH" \
    -DcomputerName=`hostname -f` \
    "-Dcom.microsoft.tfs.jni.native.base-directory=$BASE_DIRECTORY/native" \
    $RANDOM_DEVICE_PROPERTY com.microsoft.tfs.client.clc.vc.Main "$@"
```

If `hostname -f` does not actually report the same hostname that IntelliJ is determining, of course, you can simply hardcode that instead.